# SQL Query that calculates hours using variables and conditional statements is giving the wrong output

Tags: sql-server, if-statement

out of all 5 queries, this one is by far, the most difficult for me. I am trying to get this output:

> Total regular hours for the week: 544.
>     Total holiday hours for the week: 136. 
>     Total OT hours for the week: 26.

But am instead getting this:

> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
>   This week had no holiday pay.

Here is my SQL code:

```
 --Declare 5 int variables
   DECLARE @TotHours int, @TotEmps int, @HolHours int, @RegHours int, @OTHours int

--Set the Total Hours variable = to the sum total of workHours where the payperiod ID is most recent
SET @TotHours = (SELECT SUM(WorkHours) FROM Hours WHERE PPID = (SELECT MAX(PPID) FROM PayPeriod))

--Set the Holiday Hours variable = to the sum total of HolHours where the payperiod ID is most recent
SET @HolHours = (SELECT SUM(@HolHours) FROM Hours WHERE PPID = (SELECT MAX(PPID) FROM PayPeriod))

--Set the Total Employees variable = to the count of employee ID's where there is no TermDate
SET @TotEmps = (SELECT COUNT(EmpData.EmpID) FROM EmpData JOIN Work ON EmpData.EmpID = Work.EmpID WHERE EndDate IS NULL)

--Set the Regular Hours variable = to the Total Employees variable * 32
 SET @RegHours = (SELECT SUM(@TotEmps) * 32);


--(USE THIS CONDITIONAL STRUCTURE- substitute variable names where needed and remove the "--")
 IF @HolHours > 0
    BEGIN
        IF @RegHours > @TotHours
            BEGIN
            --set the Overtime Hours variable = 0
  SET @OTHours = 0
            --set the Regular Hours variable = Total Hours variable
  SET @RegHours = @TotHours

            --Place the 3 print statements here
  PRINT 'Total regular hours for the week: @TotHours.'
  PRINT 'Total holiday hours for the week: @HolHours.'
  PRINT 'Total OT Hours for the week: @OTHours.'
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
            --set the Overtime Hours variable = Total Hours variable - Regular Hours variable
  SET @OTHours = @TotHours - @RegHours

            --place the 3 print statements here

  PRINT 'Total regular hours for the week: @TotHours.'
  PRINT 'Total holiday hours for the week: @HolHours.'
  PRINT 'Total OT Hours for the week: @OTHours.'
            END
            END
ELSE 
    --Place the single print statement here (doesn't use variables)
  PRINT 'This week had no holiday pay.'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The summing of the holiday hours is wrong:

```
SET @HolHours = (SELECT SUM(@HolHours) FROM Hours WHERE PPID = (SELECT MAX(PPID) FROM PayPeriod))
```

Maybe this should this be:

```
SET @HolHours = (SELECT SUM(HolHours) FROM Hours WHERE PPID = (SELECT MAX(PPID) FROM PayPeriod))
```

Comment: Thanks. I also forgot to convert to varchar in the print statements. Now I am getting the correct output aside from RegHours being 570 instead of 544. Hmm...

Comment: @Pau808 Are you certain that `SET @TotEmps = (SELECT COUNT(EmpData.EmpID)...` is correct?  Since the query has a join I would worry that you're getting too high a count.  That is, perhaps should it be `SET @TotEmps = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT EmpData.EmpID)...`.